# How to display a message visible just once on a page

Tags: php

After a user has registered on my website, I want to display a welcome message on the next page..

I want this to be visible just once.

I tried to do this with session but the problem is - it appears every single time the user is logged in and visits that page...

```
$message2 = "Congrats!! Your store has been created successfully!";
$_SESSION['message2'] = $message2;
header("location: admin/welcome.php");
```

Am building with php....but I dont mind using jquery etc for this.

Comment: after showing make session $_SESSION['message2'] = ''; empty so that next time it wont show any text..

Comment: You need to remove the message from session manually. Do this after you display it. Prior to displaying it you should check if `$_SESSION['message2']` is empty.

Comment: Set `query` `header("location: admin/welcome.php?msg=welcome");` No need to use session.

Comment: I would have a db flag, that I would use on that user's account, by default to zero when the user have visited the page again check that flag

Comment: By the way how is this message set?

Comment: You need to sotre this inside a `Cookie` or a `Database`. The Session is the wrong place becouse it will be resetted after closing the Browser ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `welcome.php`, after the line that prints the message, [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) `$_SESSION['message2']` or empty it.

Example

```
echo $_SESSION['message2'];
unset($_SESSION['message2']);
// OR
$_SESSION['message2'] = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use GET to make it work like this:

```
header("location: admin/welcome.php?message=$message2");
```

on welcome.php page

```
if(isset($_GET['message']) && !empty($_GET['message'])){
   echo $_GET['message'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **start_session();**
After displaying first you could set a $_SESSION['displayed'] = true;
then checking if this variable is set, to avoid display a second time